# Proof that if $G$ is an abelian group and $p||G|$ then there is only one Sylow p-subgroup where all of its elements have powers of a p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, sylow-theory

I tried to proof this but I'm not sure if it's fine or if I'm missing something. Any help or hints are appreciated.
This is what I got:

By hypothesis we know that $p||G|$ then $|G|=pm$. Supposing that $p|m$ then we can factorize the prime p out of $m$ such that $|G|=p^{r}n$ and $p\nmid{n}$. By the Sylow theorem exists $H\leq{G}$ of order $p^{r}$. Suppose there exists another p-subgroup $K\leq{G}$ which elements have powers of a prime. It's clear that $K\leq{H}$. Sylow theorem also tells us that any two p-subgroups are conjugate $H=gKg^{-1}$, but remembering that $G$ is an abelian group so all of its subgroups must be abelian aswell. Then we get $H=K$ and there is only one Sylow p-group.

In the case $p\nmid{m}$ we have a Sylow p-group of order $p$ and we follow the previous steps to get the same result.

Comment: When you say that elements "have powers of a prime", do you mean that their order is a power of $p$?

Comment: Yes, they are of the form $x^{p^{s}}$

Comment: This is completely different from what I said. In general an element of the form $x^{p^s}$ has no reason to have order divisible by $p$.

Comment: Sorry, it's just that's is my first time with Sylow groups and I still don't understand them that well, but what I meant is exactly what you said on the first comment. The elements have order a power of $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read your question as asking "if $p \mid |G|$ and $G$ is Abelian, then there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup". If this is not what you meant, please let me know and I'll update my answer.

The proof that you gave in the question is *close*, but is much more complicated than it needs to be. Your plan of using the abelian-ness of $G$ to get that $P$ is unique is a good one, and it will work. But your assertion that $K \leq H$ is not true in general, and we do not need the fact that all of the subgroups of $G$ are abelian. Also, I'm not sure what your case $p \not \mid m$ at the end is about. You case on $p \div m$ at the beginning, but there is no need to do so (unless I misunderstand the result you are proving). Here is a cleaned up version of your proof:

---

Write $|G| = p^r m$ with $p \not \mid m$.

By the Sylow Theorems, we know that $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup. That is, $G$ has a subgroup $P$ of order $p^r$, as you stated in your question.

The Sylow Theorems *also* tell us that every $P' \leq G$ of order $p^r$ is conjugate to $P$. For some $g \in G$,

$$gPg^{-1} = P'$$

Again, as you note in your question, since $G$ is abelian, we have $P' = gPg^{-1} = P$. Thus, every $p$-Sylow subgroup must be equal to $P$, and so $P$ is the only one.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This is a much cleaner version. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^ if this answers your question, though, you should accept it so that other people on the site know how to spend their time

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make this distinction about whether $p$ divides $m$ or not; the whole point here is that you can define

$$H:=\{g\in G\mid\text{ord$(g)$ is a power of $p$}\}$$

and under the assumption that $G$ is abelian, you can prove this is a subgroup of $G$. Then you'll find that $|H|$ is a power of $p$, so $H$ must be contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$. But using Lagrange's theorem you can easily prove that $P\subseteq H$, so in fact we must have $H=P$.